# Find the standard deviation of X, a biased coin

Tags: probability, statistics

When tossed, a biased coin yields heads with probability 20% and tails with probability 80%. Let X denote the 
number of heads obtained when the coin is tossed 36 times. Find the standard deviation of X.

So I think I found the pdf to be (36 choose x)*(.2)^x*(.8)^x; but I'm not sure.

Standard deviation I know is (var(x))^(1/2) and var(x)=E(x^2)-(E(x))^(1/2). Knowing this, I'm not sure what to do next...

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer in the formula sqrt (n*p*(1-p))

Answer (score 1):

For a binomial distribution the variance is $np(1-p)$. Can you take it from here?